# JIRA dashboard not appear because of Javas script error

Tags: javascript, jira

I'd install Atlassian Jira successfully on my server and it's work correctly. but when I login from some clients, an error occurred on a "tzdetect" plugin and jira can't load dashboard and some feature of green hopper plugin, but in some client it's work correctly.

Javascript console log is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined com.atlassian.jira.jira-tzdetect-plugin:tzdetect-lib.js:2
```

I check this in IE, Firefox and chrome, this problem exist!
I'm sure it's client problem but don't know how can fixed!

Comment: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/296295/jira-dashboard-does-not-appear

Comment: I'd seen this link, in my case some clients can work correctly and other not! their answers not works.

Comment: After 2 days and debug **/* module-key = 'com.atlassian.jira.jira-tzdetect-plugin:tzdetect-lib', location = 'js/detect_timezone.js' */** file i found this bug occurred when client system can't determine TimeZone! because of daylight saving!
To solve the problem go to **Date and Time > Time Zone Setting** and checked **Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time.**

Comment: Dear Mahyar, I think instead of hiding this in a comment, you should answer your own questions. This is allowed and recommended. I can confirm that this is really the answer on Jira 6.0.4. The issue was fixed in 6.4.14. Instead of crashing, it warns you about a time zone mismatch.

Comment: I have exact same issue, but I don't see "Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time." where is that option? I see only "Default user time zone" and changing it doesn't solve the issue.